# Securing data for multiple users Firestore

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

How could I set rules for Firestore to restrict access only for some users to certain collections documents/collection in the following manner:

```js
//base collection
clients:{
  //document
  client-1-store:{
    users-allowed:[
      "user-1-id",
      "user-2-id",
      "user-3-id",
      "user-4-id",
    ]
  }
}
```

The thing is I'd like to only allow reading and writing to the "client-1-store" document and its documents and sub collections if the current logged in user's id is set inside the users-allowed array of each "store", but I have no idea of how i could do that...

Comment: Please read this doc to get some ideas: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access  (you can't use an array for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating an array of user IDs, create a [map of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values)

```
//base collection
clients:{
  //document
  client-1-store:{
    users-allowed:{
      "user-1-id": true,
      "user-2-id": true,
      "user-3-id": true,
      "user-4-id": true,
    }
  }
}


match /clients/{storeId=**} {
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/clients/$(storeId).data.users-allowed.$(request.auth.uid)) == true;
}
```

However, this doesn't scale as well as having an allowedUsers sub-collection, with each user ID saved as a document.  You can then use the `exists` condition, instead.  This also allows you to add further granularity to the user's document for detailed CRUD permissions.