# Flutter Firebase : a database for each user

Tags: database, firebase, flutter

Is it possible with firebase to have a database for each downloaded application?
(A downloaded application = a user + its database)

Thank

Comment: There is no `database` there, its all collections. Better to give a separate collection / node to a user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Securing data for multiple users Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667262/securing-data-for-multiple-users-firestore)

Comment: Your question is kinda asking about a Multi-Tenant situation where each user (the tenant) has their own discreet space to store their data. In that case, Firebase is not a multi-tenant database; it's a single database that all instances of your app access. That being said, you can give each user their own space within the Firebase and it can be protected via Firebase Rules; that's a common use case. Or, you can create different Apps in Firebase and provide one to each user. This is not a good solution for a high number of users, and it's somewhat hard to manage as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but that is pointless. And expensive. Use Firebase where one user is one collection, in ONE SINGLE database.

Answer (score 0):

> To clarify my question, the idea and that a user enters data every day
> (like a todolist for example) but that he is the only one to access it
> ....

From your above clarification, it looks like you want to protect each user's data from others.
Take a look at [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security):

Comment: Ok, if I understood correctly (I followed the link), only one database but each user can save / retrieve their own data ... Thanks

Comment: Yes. One database but each user has a node that contains the user information. You can then use security rules to ensure only that user has access to the information in the node. Take a look at this https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4 to understand how to model your data.

Comment: So I just have to see if this solution will not be too expensive ...